# Export all subscribers file content is in hexadecimal, I need it to be readable text

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, data-export, automationstudio, data-extract

I have an automation to export all subscribers to fetch the "status" column. My shceduled automation extracts the all subscribers list and then drops the file on the dedicated FTP with correct name and file ending (.csv). But when i open the file it only shows hexadecimal characters, why is this?

Right now i have to steps in the automation, one data extract activity and one file transfer activity.

The configuration in the data extract activity is set to **UTF-8 Encoding**, Column delimeter is set to **Default** and the format is set to **.csv**. I've checked the options *Extract Subscribers* and *Include All Subscribers*. Does anyone know how to get the file content into readable text?

Comment: For some reason the file does not have .csv file ending after export even if its specified in the configuration of the data extract acitivty. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Tracking extracts are always .zip files.

Comment: @Adam Spriggs - When i check the option "Unzip compressed file" in the File Transfer Activity after the Data Extract Activity, i get the erro message "File pattern is invalid. It must be of type: .zip, .tar, .gz, .tar.gz, .tgz". Isn't it .zip by default? It's the same error if i add .zip manually as well.

Comment: And the file doesn't have a file ending at all when it is dropped in the FPT folder which means i cannot create a File transfer activity as step 3 to unzip the file either.

Comment: In your file transfer, I believe you need to do yourfilename.zip, not yourfilename.csv - after it is moved onto your FTP, you should then be able to unzip it via the File transfer

Comment: Simple as that, thanks @Gortonington. The manual naming of the file ending .zip did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are taking a tracking extract, so please see below for necessary tasks to export onto an FTP location and unzip:

- Create and execute your data extract / tracking extract
- Create a File Transfer to move onto FTP (Move a File From Safehouse)
- Create a File Transfer to unzip your file (Manage File)

Details on these steps:

**For the tracking extract:**

- Make sure to name the File with .zip. (e.g. Tracking.zip)
- Format listed is the format of the files INSIDE the zip file.

**For the Move From Safehouse File Transfer:**

- Make sure to set to "Move a File From Safehouse" for File Action
- Mimic File Name from before (e.g. Tracking.zip)

**For the Unzip File Transfer:**

- Make sure to set to "Manage File" for File Action
- Mimic File Name from before (e.g. Tracking.zip)
- Select 'Unzip compressed file' from File Management Actions
- Make sure the file location matches Move From Safehouse File Transfer

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have not checked the 'File is compressed' checkbox in the File Transfer Activity. 
It could be that the file you are opening is a .zip file.

Comment: I dont see that option in the steps of the activity. I have choosed "Move a File From Safehouse" instead of the "Manage File" which had that option. If i choose "Manage file" option i get the error message "Automation Not Run. An error prevented Extract All subscribers automation from running. Please retry. Need more help regarding this error? Open a support case through the Help & Training Portal" when running the automation.